# ipython kernel maxes out on 3gb in a 16gb linux box?

Tags: python, linux, memory, ipython

I keep getting `MemoryError: cannot allocate memory for array` once my ipython kernel hits 3Gb on a linux 16GB box. Can you throw me leads on what am I missing?

top:

```
KiB Mem:  16599788 total,  5128780 used, 11471008 free,   114840 buffers
```

ulimit:

```
ihadanny@ubuntu:~$ ulimit
unlimited
```

versions:

```
ihadanny@ubuntu:~$ ipython --version
4.0.1
ihadanny@ubuntu:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
ihadanny@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/*rel*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

offending proc:

```
ihadanny@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/2744/status | grep Vm
VmPeak:  2975748 kB
VmSize:  2817768 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:   2864780 kB
VmRSS:   2688496 kB
VmData:  2772776 kB
VmStk:       144 kB
VmExe:      2704 kB
VmLib:     37560 kB
VmPTE:      5436 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

Comment: It sounds like your python might be 32 bit.

Comment: oh man! indeed `print sys.maxsize > 2**32` gives false :(

Comment: @Will - do you know how come I'm stuck with the 32 bit version? I installed ubuntu 14.04 and worked only with `apt-get`...

Comment: Does `uname -a` show `i686` or `x86_64`?

Comment: ihadanny@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:18:00 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Got it! So, it looks like you've actually installed 32-bit Ubuntu. Go download the 64bit version, and everything will work properly. Since you have so much ram, I can almost guarantee this is a 64bit system (which can still run 32bit code, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've installed the 32bit version of Ubuntu on a 64bit system. 32bit programs cannot address ram larger than 4GB.

So, assuming you're using Ubuntu Server, you need to re-download the 64bit version, [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). Currently, Ubuntu Server only supports 64bit. If you're using Ubuntu Desktop, go [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and download the "64-bit -- recommended" version.

After installing the correct version of Ubuntu, 64-bit Python will be installed by default.